# removing all svg elements in D3 save some specified

Tags: d3.js

```
const svg=d3.append("svg").attr(...)
const g1=svg.append("g").attr("id","g1").attr(...)
var v1=g1.append(...)
... // many other nested append operations 
const g2=g1.append("g").attr("id","g2").attr(...)
var v2=g2.append(...)
... // many other nested append operations
```

Then how can I remove all elements from `svg` object apart groups `g1` and `g2`?
Something similar to:

```
svg.selectAll("*:not('#g1'):not('#g2')").remove();
```

that does not work.

Comment: Your selector string is just a bit off: the `not()` pseudo-class does not need any quotation marks around the IDs. `svg.selectAll("*:not(#g1):not(#g2)").remove();` will work perfectly fine. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/cv1qse84/.

Comment: I am voting to close this as it's just a minor typo.

Comment: @altocumulus I don't think the typo fixes @tic's question. Although your correction is correct, all descendants of the `g1` and `g2` elements are also removed by that operation, which I doubt is what @tic is after.

Comment: @matthias.rocks In that case a `svg.selectAll("svg>g:not(#g1):not(#g2)").remove();` will do. https://jsfiddle.net/856prkco/ There is not enough information in the question to provide a more elaborate answer that does not resort to guessing.

Comment: @altocumulus That is indeed a good solution, and it fits well with @tic's outlined example. Perhaps changing it to `svg.selectAll("svg>*:not(#g1):not(#g2)").remove()` to remove all descendants of the `svg` and not just the `g` elements.

Comment: @altocumulus: you're right, I made a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

I would apply a class to all elements that you want to keep, e.g.:

```
const svg=d3.append("svg")
  .attr(...)

const g1=svg.append("g")
  .attr(...)
  .classed('doKeep', true)

var v1=g1.append(...)

// After adding many nested elements to g1
g1.selectAll('*')
  .classed('doKeep', true)

...

const g2=g1.append("g")
  .attr(...)
  .classed('doKeep', true)

var v2=g2.append(...)
...

// After adding many nested elements to g1
g2.selectAll('*')
  .classed('doKeep', true)
```

Then you can select all elements in you SVG that do not have that class, with a [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) CSS selector as such:

```
svg.selectAll(':not(.doKeep)').remove()
```

The inverse would also work, where you mark all elements you want to delete, and then delete them after selecting them. But giving the phrasing of your question, this is the most accurate approach.

Hope this helps!

*Edit: Updated to reflect updated question that specifies many nested elements.*